# Flutter, how to move leading and action on SliverAppbar to the bottom

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

im making a notes app like this :

[image: My current app]

as you can see, my title is below the leading and action icon, but I want to make it reverse like this:

[image: My Target Layout]

how can i make it like that? Here's my code :

```
SliverAppBar(
        leading: Icon(
          Icons.menu,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        actions: const [
          Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
          SizedBox(width: 8),
          Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.black),
          SizedBox(width: 14),
        ],
        elevation: 2,
        pinned: true,
        floating: true,
        backgroundColor: kLightBGColor,
        expandedHeight: 150,
        flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
          title: Text(
            'My Notes',
            style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.grey.shade900,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
            ),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 1):

The best I could do was use a second `SliverAppBar` on top of the first, with some adjustments to both of their parameters. You may want to further customize to your preference:

```
CustomScrollView(
  slivers: [
    SliverAppBar(
      elevation: 0,
      pinned: true,
      floating: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      expandedHeight: 80,
      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
        title: Text(
          'My Notes',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey.shade900,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
          ),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
    ),
    SliverAppBar(
      leading: Icon(
        Icons.menu,
        color: Colors.black,
      ),
      actions: const [
        Icon(Icons.search, color: Colors.black),
        SizedBox(width: 8),
        Icon(Icons.more_vert, color: Colors.black),
        SizedBox(width: 14),
      ],
      pinned: true,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      expandedHeight: 45,
      collapsedHeight: 45,
      toolbarHeight: 20,
    ),
  ],

  ...
  
),
```

Comment: This code can create a layout similar to my target, but the problem is that the two appbars can't merge into one when swiping up until they collapse.

Comment: That's just not available with the current widgets. Probably for design reasons. The Text title is meant to be in context with the content that you are showing. If you title is above the AppBar, it's separated from your content. It's not a very good user experience.